# If the UK left the EU, would that affect people in the UK who work for German companies?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

If the UK were to leave the EU, would it have any noticeable impact on my working life due to the fact that I work in the UK for a German company?

Edit for clarification: I am UK born and bred

Comment: It might well do. This depends on what sort of visa (and other) arrangements are put in place as part of the exit negotiations .

Answer (score 4):

At this stage, it's very difficult to know how the negotiations would go and to determine what the relationship between the UK and the EU would look like so any answer is necessarily quite speculative. Once we know what the conditions really would be, it might be possible to make some predictions on their likely impact on the economy but even that would be quite difficult.

Those in favour of a break with the EU often paint a rosy picture in which the UK is able to get what it wants and maintain unfettered access to the single market while sceptics tend to assume that the EU cannot offer to renege on some core principle like the freedom of movement for persons but at this stage it's mostly guesswork (and possibly quite a bit of bluff/wishful thinking on both sides).

It's however possible to review the main issues and see *what* could be impacted (if not necessarily *how* those things would actually be impacted). It seems that there are at least three areas in which all this could have an impact on your working life:

- **Rules on working conditions and health and safety at work.** To level the playing field within the single market, the EU enacted rules on things like working times, paid leave, sickness, gender equality and discriminations at work, etc. that are binding for the UK. The UK was traditionally among the most reluctant countries in Europe so something like the working time rules might not exist if it wasn't for the EU.

  On the other hand, in spite of all the noise, most of these rules aren't extraordinarily constraining and broadly similar rules exist in pretty much any half-way modern country, save perhaps for the US (think parental leave) and the UK would probably have adopted something like that on its own even if it never was part of the EU to begin with. So I would not expect any dramatic change, at least not at first.

  And even if the UK leaves the EU, all the rules would first remain in place as they have become part of the law. But once they are decoupled from the treaties, all it takes to change them is an act of Parliament. In this respect, the EU is a kind of ‘commitment device‘: as a worker, you know that whatever government comes next, it won't be able to renege on these basic guarantees so easily. Once the UK is out, these rights would not be abolished but could be slowly eroded (say by introducing stricter eligibility conditions, new exceptions, etc.).

  (Therein incidentally lies the strongest case against the EU: Its institutions are ultimately controlled by broadly democratic governments but, even with the EU parliament in the mix, the process is removed from the voters through several layers of decision-making – the UK parliament elects a government whose prime minister seats in a council which names a commission which prepares legislation with another council made of governments' representatives… – and once something is decided, it's very difficult to roll back, which is not ideal for a democracy. There is no one election that could prompt a change of direction.)
- **Access to the single market.** It's sometimes difficult to understand what this entails precisely but that's probably the most important realisation of the EU. It's not merely about trade and exports; nowadays, goods flow easily, the external tariff is low and the UK would still sell a lot of the stuff to the EU, no matter what. What this is about are things like technical norms, or certifications and authorisations.

  One thing many people do not realise is that the EU is not pushing tons of rules on the smallest things out of mission creep or because German and French bureaucrats have a secret plan to take over the world. Rather, the rules on the shape of cucumbers or any other funny example you might dig up are really a direct result of the single market idea. The goal is to make sure that once a product is fit for consumption and sale in one country, it's automatically accepted in the others, no need to start from scratch with tests, paperwork, etc.

  That's why consumer protection rules, certification marks, labels, trading standards and the like have to be moved to the EU level and also why some countries which decided to stay out of the EU like Norway or Iceland ultimately have to implement pretty much all the rules, one by one. You can't pick and choose or get rid of the apparent silliness and keep the single market alive.

  Because of that, EU economies, while not perfectly unified, are integrated to a far deeper level than what international trade agreements allow. And you can easily use a UK branch to serve the whole EU. A country like Ireland used this very explicitly to position itself as a gateway to Europe. And the UK has many of the same advantages than Ireland (the language, qualified workforce, favourable regulations, etc.). It's less visible but it matters too. To the extent that leaving the EU would put the UK out of the single market, it could make the country less attractive for foreign investment and have some long-lasting impact on the economy. How much and whether it's worth it is another question.
- **Freedom of movement for workers.** At first sight, it might not seem to be of direct concern to you as a British citizen but this is really another facet of the single market. As such, it's also part of what makes the country attractive and more generally makes the UK economy more efficient.

  There is strong evidence that on the whole, immigration (from within or outside the EU) is beneficial to the UK in economic terms. Unless you are in a profession that's directly exposed to the competition and you lost your job or felt pressure on your income as a result, you stand to gain from it and to lose from any change that makes coming to the UK to work more difficult.

  As far as the transition to a post-EU UK is concerned, it's pretty safe to assume that nearly all the workers currently in the country would be “grand-fathered” into whatever system is created at the time. There would also naturally be some visa/residence program for highly skilled workers like there is everywhere else (and in any EU country, including the UK, for non-EU citizens). So your employer's operations would not be immediately threatened.

  But freedom of movement for workers is much more than that. For an employer, it's the guarantee they can hire any EU citizen without any special paperwork, delay or concern about being bitten by some rule or quota. For a (prospective) employee, it's the certainty that they can take a job in another EU country without giving up anything (that's actually still a work in progress in areas like pensions but that's the idea). You don't need to give your notice before you know whether you visa will come through and you can always come back to the country you left at some point in the future if you want to.

  Consequently, that means a UK-based employer has a broader pool of potential employees to recruit from and a company can choose any location in the EU and get the same benefit. In theory, it means that the each company can attract the employees it needs at the right price, thus making the whole economy more productive.

  Interestingly, even though it decided to stay out of not only the EU but also the EEA, Switzerland still had to grant the same rights to all EU citizens to gain access to the single market. Beyond the symbolic weight of the membership in this or that organisation, that's the real issue. It's extremely difficult to see how you could compromise on this without killing the single market.

  Of course, adding a bit of “friction” would not create any insurmountable problem for your employer but it could still contribute to making the UK slightly less attractive as a place of business and therefore impact you too.

Regarding the last two points, working for a German company might make a difference, not mainly because Germany would be in the EU while the UK would not but simply because it would have to reevaluate its international strategy. Small and middle-size UK businesses might lose a bit through increased costs and bureaucracy for exports. A few of them might even seriously suffer because things like bidding on contracts abroad becomes more difficult. But they are not going anywhere.

Large companies, by contrast, have more flexibility. When comes the time to reorganise some department or to create a new one, a German or US company might decide to put its European operations in Ireland or the Netherlands instead of the UK. Even “British” companies (in terms of ownership or headquarters) might consider it. Like I said at the beginning, it's all quite speculative, but this risk to see the UK become a little bit less attractive for your employer and its competitors is what could have the most impact on you in my opinion.

I can also offer an anecdote related to all this. When I applied for my PhD in the Netherlands, someone from Turkey applied around the same time. At the end of the day, he was recruited before me but he started several months later than me because of all the time needed to get certified copies and translations of all the required documents and for the visa application to make its way through various government offices.

Once funding for my position was approved, I was able to start within a month or two. For him the process took something like 9 months. That's time lost for everybody. Whatever other benefits we might hope to get from it, controlling or creating restrictions on free movement (whether for persons or for other things) first means adding a lot of bureaucracy and raw inefficiencies.

(Note that the freedom of movement for persons includes several other components, with different rules for “economically non-active” persons but since you asked about your working life, I left that aspect out of the discussion).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no one knows yet as it will depend on any detailed exit negotiations with the other European countries. It is *possible* all non-UK people would need visas to work in the UK for example and the all UK people would need visas to work in other European countries.

Comment: I am not sure the OP is not a British citizen.